# Automating / scripting TFS database refresh

Tags: sql-server, tfs

I am attempting to refresh a TFS 2015 test environment on a regular basis. The TFS production environment consists out of 3 servers, and the test environment has the exact same layout (separate App, Build and SQL server - no sharepoint involved).

TFS version : 14.0.23128.0 (Tfs2015)
SQL Server 2012 SP2 CU-1
OS :     Windows 2008 R2 Enterprise

Seeing that the refresh will occur regularly and to minimize down time, I want to automate / script the process to be execute at night.
Getting a production back-up from the SQL Server seems no problem, as this could be scheduled from within the TFS Admin Console (Scheduled backups).
At this stage I am trying to figure out how the “scheduled restore” will work. In no time I was bumping my head against attempting to stop all collections before the restore starts on the test environment...

My question: Is such an **automated** style of TFS backup and **restore** doable,  and is there by any chance a product out there that supports this out of the box?

Comment: I am also interested in this exact scenario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To provide a bit of feedback on the issue.
The requirements were fairly simple in our case in the sense that we only wanted the version control databases restored.
This simplified things a bit as restoring functionality such as reporting, builds, sharepoint etc. were left out of scope.

In the end I did succeed in getting the process automated to an extent, by making use of an amalgamation of SQL server stored procedures, Powershell and some standard Tfs commands.

The first step was to get the production Tfs databases backed up.
This was achieved by making use of SQL server stored procures. 
Note: You must back up all of the databases to the same time stamp to help ensure against data loss!
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/tfs/admin/backup/backup-db-architecture

These database backups are then copied to a shared restore location where the test environment’s Tfs SQL Server can access them during the restore process.
This was also done via some SQL stored procedures.
These steps are scheduled within SQL Server to execute nightly, with the previous day’s backup in the shared location being overwritten each time.

For the orchestration of the restore actions involved, TeamCity was used. 
When a restore is requested you can initiate (or schedule) it via TeamCity.

1. The first step will be to stop all the test environment’s Tfs collections.
   This was done by using the TfsServiceControl.exe - https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/tfs/command-line/tfsservicecontrol-cmd
2. Next we will execute some stored procedures on the test environment’s SQL Server that will start the DB restore process of the test environment’s Tfs DB’s.
3. The next steps will prepare the Tfs databases to run in the test environment and among other things, clear away the production values that are embedded in them.
   This was done by a PowerShell script that in essence just calls the commands that will be run when a manual restore is done. Most of the commands reside within the TfsConfig command.
   https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/tfs/commandline/tfsconfig-cmd

TfsConfig PrepareClone

TfsConfig ChangeServerID

TfsConfig RemapDBs

TfsConfig  Accounts /ResetOwner

TfsConfig  Accounts /add

TfsConfig  registerDB

TfsConfig  ConfigureMail

TfsConfig  RebuildWarehouse

Clearing cache

4. After these steps were completed the test environment’s Tfs collections are started. 
   This is done by using the TfsServiceControl.exe - https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/tfs/command-line/tfsservicecontrol-cmd

It is now possible to request or schedule a restore. A bit primitive, but so far it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup automated refresh for every MSSQL database. I would do it using SQLAgent task. Restore command should be preceded with following statement to ensure all connections are terminated otherwise restore will fail:

```
ALTER   DATABASE TFS_POC
SET     RESTRICTED_USER
WITH    ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
GO
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice Maaykel. This will take care of the DB restore. The unknown however, is the scripting / automation actions that are needed to bring the application server down etc. , before meddling with the database :- )

Answer (score 0):

There is not a way to have a total automated style of TFS restore, no matter you are using TFSBackup.exe, or using Restore Databases in Scheduled Backups, selecting your database backup is required. Also, stopping services is necessary, as stopping services helps protect against data loss or corruption during the restoration process.